# Selenium C# ExpectedConditions with IWebElement

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to make a class WaitForElement with methods likes
But ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible expect (By) not (IWebElement)

```
class WaitForElement
    {
(...)
public void waitUntilElementIsVisible(IWebElement element)
       {
           WebDriverWait webDriverWait = GetWebDriverWait();
           webDriverWait.Until ( ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(element) );
       }
```

In my PageObject classes I use

```
 public IWebElement orderTab => Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'order')]"));
```

so I wanted to use it like that:

```
WaitForElement.waitUntilElementIsVisible(orderTab)
```

Is there any option to make it works?
I can't use

```
public By orderTab => By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'order')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

The code to wait for an element to be visible is actually very simple.

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'order')]")).Displayed);
```

I like to create extension methods for the WebDriverWait class for things like this:

```
namespace OpenQa.Selenium
{
    public static class WebDriverWaitExtensions
    {
        public static bool UntilElementIsDisplayed(this WebDriverWait wait, By locator)
        {
            return wait.Until(driver => driver.FindElement(locator).Displayed);
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it, all you need is a WebDriverWait object and `using OpenQa.Selenium;` at the top of the C# file:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

wait.UntilElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'order')]"));
```